# Join the records with sql?

Tags: sql, join

I have a table with those 5 rows.

```
code | type_id | status
-----+--------+--------
123  | 123456 | DONE
123  | 456789 | DONE
321  | 654321 | DONE
321  | 897321 | DONE
456  | 999888 | DONE
456  | 777666 | FAIL
```

And I want to change it to below with DONE only.

```
code | type_id1 | type_id2
-----+----------+---------
123  | 123456   | 456789
321  | 654321   | 897321
456  | 999888   | null
```

How can I join them to show the result?

Comment: Never more than 2 type_id's per code?

Comment: Can the same type_id be repeated for a code?

Comment: SELECT nvl(a.code,  b.code)
          AS "code",
       a.type_id AS "type_id1",
       b.type_id AS "type_id2"
  FROM (SELECT *
          FROM table
         WHERE status = 'DONE') a
       FULL JOIN (SELECT *
                    FROM table
                   WHERE status = 'DONE') b
          ON a.code = b.code;

Comment: this is what i come up~ but too messy~ thank you very much for the reply!! i learn a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly that you want one row per `code`, you can use aggregation:

```
select code,
       min(type_id) as type_id1,
       (case when min(type_id) <> max(type_id) then max(type_id) end) as type_id2
from t
where status = 'DONE'
group by code;
```

Note that SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  With your sample data, there is no way to preserve "the original" order of the values, because that is undefined -- unless another column specifies that ordering.

Answer (score 3):

You can use aggregation

```
select 
    code, 
    min(type) type1, 
    case when count(*) > 1 then max(type) end type2 
from mytable
group by code
```

Note that this only works as expected if a `code` has 1 or 2 `type`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `LEFT JOIN`, for example:

```
SELECT 
     A.code, 
     A.type_id, 
     B.type_id
FROM table A 
     LEFT JOIN 
     table B ON A.code = B.code AND A.type_id <> B.type_id AND A.status = B.status
WHERE A.status = 'DONE'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cte as (select code, type_id, status, row_number() over(partition by code order by code) as rank from table)

```
select * from cte where rank =1 and status ='Done'
```